# PostgreSQL crashes upon startup

Tags: postgresql

Every time I restart my Mac OS X Version 10.8.3. and open PSQL Version 9.2.4.3 (14), the PSQL terminal appears for a second and then shuts down.

Below is the info from the docs http://postgresapp.com/documentation

Uninstalling

What I do to remedy the problem is type these 3 lines of code in bash: 
    open ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres  --> I delete the Var folder
    sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=65536
    sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216

When I restart PSQL, it works. **The problem I have an empty database. All my work is gone. 
How can I get PSQL running permantely so that I do not have to restart with an empty database?**

Comment: I don't know if this is an option for your, but Postgres 9.3 "fixed" this problem by requiring much less System V shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those values in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and they will be read on boot

Mine is:

```
[codyc:~]$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
kern.sysv.shmmax=1073741824
kern.sysv.shmall=1073741824
```

Comment: What is /etc/sysctl.conf and how do i navigate to it will bash prompt? I'm assuming once I am inside that folder in can copy and paste your code:

Comment: `/etc/sysctl.conf` is a plain text file - the cat command displays the contents of the file. Edit or create the file and enter the values you want to use. sysctl.conf is a system configuration file - for more info try [man sysctl.conf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html)